# Grammatical error in sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Why is the following sentence wrong grammatically : "I have good knowledge of Spanish."

I can't find any mistake in here, and also "I have good knowledge **about** Spanish" would be correct then ?

The correct answer is given as "I have **a** good knowledge of Spanish."

What is the grammar rule being violated here in these cases ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it _was_ wrong grammatically; it's just that we normally refer to '**a** good knowledge of [a subject'. 'Knowledge about' isn't idiomatic either.

Comment: Any test claiming that it's somehow "incorrect" to omit the indefinite article in [***{someone} has {a} good knowledge of {something}***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+good+knowledge+of%2Chas+a+good+knowledge+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20good%20knowledge%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20a%20good%20knowledge%20of%3B%2Cc0) isn't worth taking, imho.

Comment: It introduces a particular instance of "good knowledge", your knowledge. We say "knowledge of" but "knowledgeable about".

Comment: Thank you everyone :) appreciated

Comment: I’m closing this question because it asks what's wrong with a sentence that isn't wrong.